# How do I consume a rest api with a React isomorphic application

Tags: rest, reactjs, universal, isomorphic

I have an Isomorphic React application (sometimes called a Universal React application) that consumes a Rest API. However, all of the API calls happen on the client side. I am trying to figure out how to make a rest API call from the server side before the application gets rendered.

Comment: you can use something like `isomorphic-fetch` to make a call before you're initial rendertostring call

Comment: I fixed it by wrapping a `fetch.client.js` and and `fetch.server.js`. React let's you specify which one to use with the browser and main properties.

You can see the code at the link below.

https://github.com/jamrizzi/reaction/tree/master/src/core/fetch